# Angular: How can I pass down a variable from service to a nested service?

Tags: angular, typescript

In short what I'm trying to achieve is that the `ProductService` passes down a string to the `FacadeService` which in turn passes it down to the `APIService` (or perhaps directly from `ProductService` to `APIService` without instantiating it in `ProductService`?).

I do not want to call the `APIService` directly from the `ProductService`, because I want to keep the `FacadeService` there as main access point. I don't need the variable in the `FacadeService` itself, it only has to pass it down to the `APIService` because it is the only connection point to the `FacadeService`.

The code is as follows (stripped down to illustrate my idea):

**ProductService.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductService {
  private controllerName = 'product'; // <-- This one needs to be passed down
  
  constructor(private facadeService: FacadeService<Product>) {}
}
```

**FacadeService.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class FacadeService<T> {
  constructor(private api: APIService<T>) {}
}
```

**APIService.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class APIService<T> {
  private baseUrl = 'https://localhost:1337/api/';
  private url: string;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private controllerName: string // <-- NEED IT HERE
  ) {
    this.url = this.baseUrl + controllerName;
  }
}
```

How do I achieve this? Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be describing a circular dependency problem. Product depends on Facade that depends on API that depends on Product. Maybe you can pass the parameter along in the actual calls to APIService methods instead of having the constructor depend on it.

So, you would have in Product Service a call to FacadeService:

```
methodThatUsesFacadeService() {
  this.facadeService.foo(this.controllerName);
}
```

And then in FacadeService:

```
foo(controllerName: string) {
  this.APIService.bar(controllerName);
}
```

Then APIService only needs to store the baseUrl, as it will receive the controllerName when it is needed.

Comment: So that means I'll have to pass the controller name for every single function I call? That will work, but it will bloat my code a lot. It just has to pass down 1 string variable, it never changes.